# TypeError: Saw an object that is an instance of a strict subclass of EagerTensor

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build a simple model in Tensorflow 2.1.0 with Keras layers.

However, running this code:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def main():
    max_input_length = 20
    vocab_size = 10

    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 16, input_length=max_input_length))
    # ..

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Throws a `TypeError` exception:

> TypeError: Saw an object that is an instance of a strict subclass of EagerTensor, which is not supported.  Item 0 is type: tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, it worked perfectly fine in Google colab with tensorflow version `2.1.0`. No errors.

**Code-**

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def main():
    max_input_length = 20
    vocab_size = 10

    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 16, input_length=max_input_length))
    # ..

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output -**

```
2.1.0
```